# Dropbox links in server.properties file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-resource-packs

I have a Minecraft server with Crackshot Guns. And it needed a texture pack, so I made my own. It works when I use it as a resource pack (like putting it in my resource pack folder). Then I uploaded it to Dropbox and used the direct download link in my server.properties file: `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xj3kc2muyx0eehw/COD.zip?dl=1#` but it didnt work. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj3kc2muyx0eehw/COD.zip?dl=0) is the Dropbox page. Also I tried using the resource pack from another computer with a different account. Also, if this helps, in my server resource pack folder, it just says `legacy`. P.S. When I join it says loading, then a percentage increases for a minute, it lags out, and then it uses default Minecraft resource pack.

Comment: Your second Dropbox link is only visible to you. Can you change it to the public link?

Comment: Ok. I'll try...

Comment: I think it is... It says people with link can see it... I think

Comment: The link that you have up now is for your Dropbox account only. Can you put up the public link?

Comment: Hmm... When I click it, it sends me to my pack.

Comment: Oh! Here we go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj3kc2muyx0eehw/COD.zip?dl=0

Comment: Asking for upvotes tends to make the opposite happen.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to remember that. I'm new so...

Comment: [Crackshot Guns](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/crackshot) appears to be a server plugin. Hence, this question is off-topic as tech support for modded minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support for modded Minecraft is off-topic on Arqade. It is too difficult to attempt to answer every modded MC question.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't tell what you've done wrong (It all seems fine), this is just a guide to setting up a server resource pack. If you follow these instructions, it's bound to work. This is assuming you're using the server which you can download from the minecraft website, and that you've set it up properly.

1. Make or find a resource pack.
2. Check it works by putting it into your resource packs folder.
3. If it works, upload it to a file sharing service (I recommend [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com)).
4. Copy the download link (on Dropbox, you can find the download link by clicking 'share' next to the file name).
5. Paste this link into your server.properties file, under resource-pack.
6. Change the link to a direct download link if it isn't already. (If you're using dropbox, change the dl=0 part at the end of the link to dl=1)
7. Launch your server!

Make sure that the people joining your server haven't set the server resource pack option (On the add server screen in-game) to OFF.

I hope this helps! If there's any problems with this answer, or questions about it, leave a comment, and I'll try to get back to as many people as possible.